# How to update to sklearn 1.1.3 in google colab

Tags: installation, scikit-learn, pip, google-colaboratory, version

I love google colab, but I would like to use `sklearn` version 1.1.3 because I'm using `CCA`, which has changed from version 1.0.2 (what colab comes with) and version 1.1.3 (which is the current stable release).

I've tried to do so with

```
!pip install scikit-learn==1.1.3
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

But I get the following error message

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn==1.1.3 (from versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.15.0b1, 0.15.0b2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16b1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17b1, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.18, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19b2, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.20.4, 0.21rc2, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22rc2.post1, 0.22rc3, 0.22, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.22.2.post1, 0.23.0rc1, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.24.dev0, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 1.0rc1, 1.0rc2, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn==1.1.3
1.0.2
```

It seems like google colab just doesn't have higher than 1.0.2

Does anyone know of a good workaround that good let me use version 1.1.3 of `sklearn`?

Comment: Hint: check your Python version and compare it with minimal requirements at https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/1.1.3/ (in the left column).